# Creating hyperlink from text in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uilabel

I have a json file which has all the information in text. 
One of the node in json looks like this :

```
"description": "File. <a href=\\\"http://www.test.com/VerifyFile.html\\\">Verify File</a>"
```

What I would like to do is create a hyperlink in a UILabel textfield in swift like :

```
File ***Verify File***
```

I tried to do lookup on stackoverflow but nothing was concrete available. I wrote the following code to get the "href" text using Regex.

```
let regexOptions:NSRegularExpressionOptions?
                = NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "<a[^>]+href=\"(.*?)\"[^>]*>.*?</a>", options: regexOptions!)
```

And then use NSMUtableAttributedString to create a link of it. Am I in the correct direction ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38035556/multi-line-editable-piece-of-text-editable-uilabel/38035564#38035564

Comment: No sorry, there is no way, because UILabel doesn't have gesture recognizer (for example UIButton has UITapGestureRecognizer). You could change the UILabel to UIButton, that way the whole text would be a link.

Comment: @impression7vx thanks for the answer...I will try it out....

Comment: @TParizek I dont need to change to UIButton....It seems you didnt understand my question. Impression has answered it

Comment: i would have typed it out to your specifications, but if you basically know what you are doing, the answer I provided on the other post should suffice. Feel Free to upvote!

Comment: TTTAttributedLabel should be able to accomplish this once you distill the url out of the json string

Comment: @impression7vx yeah it works...but I do still need to detect start of <a href>...in your example there is already an assumption of a website name....but I need to do that too.

Comment: Ahh! yea , my website name was pre-determined in my example. Sorry bout that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a good approach but you will work more than if your json only have the essential information: { "description": link" } so you can use a UIButton with a @IBAction attached to open a WebController or something like that with the link.